# Should be a quick question about Enterprise Search Center vs standard search

Tags: permissions

For the search center, once set up you wouldn't want to give it to everyone in your company right?

If search center can search across applications and site collections, that seems like a decent access to information.
For example, the warehouse manager won't need access to search center because if he did, he can search up on something like sales reports and that'll show up.

Or can you isolate/selectively restrict access within search center?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint Search has a concept called [Security Trimming](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn167721.aspx) which will exclude search results that a user does not have permission to view. As long as the permissions are set up correctly on your resources, there shouldn't be any concern about multiple people having access to the same search center, because the results will be trimmed for each user based on their permissions.